# How do i create composite unique key in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

How to create a unique key on multiple columns in a collection in mongodb. like we use this ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`user`, `email`, `phonenumber`); in sql.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this

```
db.members.createIndex( { groupNumber: 1, lastname: 1, firstname: 1 },
{ unique: true } )
```

Check this link for more information
[mongodb create unique index](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/)